# Evaluating Complex Expressions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to evaluate the value(s) of the following expressions, giving my answers in the form $x+iy$. I believe I've attempted the first few correctly, but the last one I'm completely baffled on.

a) $i^i = (0+i)^i = (cos(\frac\pi2)+isin(\frac\pi2))^i = (e^{i\frac\pi2})^i = e^{-\frac\pi2} \approx 0.20788$

b) $e^{sin(i)} = e^{\frac1{2i}(e^{i*i}-e^{-i*i})} = e^{\frac i2(e^{1}-e^{-1})} = e^{\frac e2 - i \frac 1{2e}} = e^{\frac e2}(cos(\frac 1{2e}) + isin(\frac 1{2e})) \approx 3.8272 + 0.7120i$

c) $\sqrt{1+i} = (\sqrt2e^{i \frac \pi4})^{\frac12} = \sqrt[4]2 e^{i \frac \pi8} = \sqrt[4]2(cos(\frac \pi8) + isin(\frac \pi8)) \approx 1.0967 + 0.4551i$

d) $exp(Log(3+4i))$ = ...

On this last one I don't know what to do. I believe this would be using the principal logarithm which would mean $Log z = ln |z| + Arg z$ but I don't see how this would simplify my equation in any way...

Also,  the problem statement says "value(s)". Do any of these actually take other values than the ones I have found?

Comment: Have you tried verifying your answers using a CAD, for example WolframAlpha or Maple or Mathematica?

Answer (score 0):

Very good question!

d) The logarithm $Log$ is just the inverse of the exponential function $Exp$, but have 'more branches' as you say, i.e. can take more values, as $Exp$ is not injective. So, because they are inverses to each other, one answer will be $3+4i$. Can you find the other ones?

In all other cases you miss values. Keep in mind that $e^{2\pi i}=1$, so e.g. in a) when you wrote $i=e^{i\frac\pi2}$, you could have equally well written $i=e^{i\frac{5\pi}2}$ or $i=e^{i\frac{-7\pi}2}$.

In c) the other square root will be (not so surprisingly) the negative of your result.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about figuring out what other solutions of (d) there would be... Is that when I would use the principle logarithm?